# finding line in plane perpendicular to another line

Tags: cross-product

I have a vector that I need to find. It is in the (111) plane. The vector I need to find is perpendicular to another vector which is parallel to [01-1].

To be clear:

I want to find A which lies in the (111) plane.
Another vector, B, is parallel to [01-1]
A is perpendicular to B.

How can I find A?

Would I take the cross product of (111) and [01-1]?

Comment: What is "the plane (111)?"

Comment: In a crystal, the plane is the (111) plane

Comment: Please define in mathematical terminology.  Is the normal to this plane $\hat x+\hat y+\hat z$?

Comment: Im not really sure, If you google (111) crystal plane, it shows a picture.

Comment: I think you are right, that x+y+z is normal

Comment: Essentially, I want a vector perpendicular to vector within 111 plane

Comment: To define a plane, we need information about it (e.g., $3$ points on the plane, a normal vector and $1$ point on the plane).  You have not defined the plane as far as I can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need a vector which is perpendicular to the normal $(1, 1, 1)$ of the plane and perpendicular to $(0, 1, -1)$, so you need to work out the cross product